# Textboxs vanish when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am having an issue after using some Jquery.

I am using VS 2013, asp.net, VB.

I have a panel on the page that shows when a row is selected from a gridview.  It contains several text boxes and also a dropdownlist.  I have a jquery script that hides/shows text boxes on the page depending what is selected from the dropdownlist.  The code is below.

```
 <script>
    function jScript() {

            $('#LowerText').hide();
            $('#UpperText').hide();
            $('#min').hide();
            $('#max').hide();
            $('#CommentsText').hide();
            $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "200px" })

            $('#AssetStatusChoice').change(function () {
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Fully Available")
            {
                $('#CommentsText').hide();
                $('#LowerText').hide();
                $('#UpperText').hide();
                $('#min').hide();
                $('#max').hide();
                $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "200px" })

            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Restricted")
            {
                $('#LowerText').show();
                $('#UpperText').show();
                $('#CommentsText').show();
                $('#min').show();
                $('#max').show();
                $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "340px" })


            }
            if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Unavailable")
            {
                $('#LowerText').hide();
                $('#UpperText').hide();
                $('#min').hide();
                $('#max').hide();
                $('#CommentsText').show();
                $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "280px" })


            }
        });
        };

            </script>
```

This works fine.

When the user clicks the commit button on the panel the data entered in the textboxes is saved to an MS SQL DB.  I have added some code for each text box to validate whats added to it (so its not blank or there are letters where there should be numbers).  An example of this code is shown below.  It changes the colour of the border if there is an error.  Also I have added a line of code to stop the SQL stored procedure excecuting if there is a validation issue.

```
Dim isValid As Boolean
    isValid = True
    Dim intValidate As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TimeTextHrs.Text, intValidate) Or TimeTextHrs.Text = "" Then

        AssetPopUp.Show()
        TimeTextHrs.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        isValid = False

    End If
```

My issue is when the user clicks commit within the panel the boxes that are now visible because of what was selected within the dropdownlist vanish as if it reloads the panel.  I need them to remain visible.  If you look at the JQuery above you can see when restricted is selected from the dropdownlist 3 textboxes show.  When the user hits commit these vanish.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: You really like to repeat your code over and over.

Comment: thanks for the helpful comment.  I am just running through a test so I will clean it up when I go into production.  Its the first jquery I have used so I am learning still.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to run some js when the page loads  to set visibility.

You should also consider refactoring this logic so it is more maintainable.

```
       $(function() {

       if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Fully Available")
        {
            $('#CommentsText').hide();
            $('#LowerText').hide();
            $('#UpperText').hide();
            $('#min').hide();
            $('#max').hide();
            $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "200px" })

        }
        if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Restricted")
        {
            $('#LowerText').show();
            $('#UpperText').show();
            $('#CommentsText').show();
            $('#min').show();
            $('#max').show();
            $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "340px" })


        }
        if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val() == "Unavailable")
        {
            $('#LowerText').hide();
            $('#UpperText').hide();
            $('#min').hide();
            $('#max').hide();
            $('#CommentsText').show();
            $('#ChangeStatusPnl').css({ "height": "280px" })


        }
```

});